# Swift UI tests - XCTAssertEqual has the wrong behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently trying to do some tests in my iOS application but I'm facing a problem.

Here is my code (I will explain the issue right after) :

```
let passwordField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
passwordField.tap()
passwordField.typeText("Password")

let password = passwordField.value as? String
guard let testPassword = password, !testPassword.isEmpty else {
    XCTFail("Authentication tests failed : password field is wrongly formatted.")
    return
}

XCTAssertNotEqual(password, "Random password")
XCTAssertEqual(password, "Password")
```

The **XCTAssertNotEqual** part is good, but the **XCTAssertEqual** isn't.
Here is the error :

```
XCTAssertEqual failed : (“Optional(“********”)”) is not equal to (“Optional(“Password”)”)
```

Does anyone have an idea why does it throw this error ? I guess that I have to "play" with the fact that this is a secure text but I didn't find any answer yet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should access the `text` instead of `value` in UITextField.

Comment: Unfortunatly it is not an UITextField (it is an XCUIElement) so the only way I can get the "test" is to get the value of the field casting with the wanted type.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `XCTAssertEqual`.

The first statement

```
XCTAssertNotEqual(password, "Random password")
```

is right, because:

```
`*********` is not equal "Random password"
```

The second one fails because of the error message you see in the console.

Personally, I think your logic for testing here is a bit messed up. First of all, i think there is no interface for `XCUIElement` to reverse the secure text to normal text.

Second, why would you like to verify, what is in the `textField`? It will be for sure, whatever you type in there, there is no point to test a native iOS UI element very basic functionality.

If you would like to test the authentication, than try to sign in with an incorrect password, and than with a correct one, and test the responses from you BE